# Printing services and Receivers from AndroidManifest.XML in Python

Tags: android, python, xml, parsing, manifest

I am trying to print all the permissions, features, min sdk version, services, content providers, broadcast receivers used in a Android Manifest file by Python. 
I wrote a code where permissions and features can be printed, but it is showing a null value when printing the services and content providers.

Here is my Android Manifest Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:installLocation="auto" package="com.nianticlabs.pokemongo" 
 platformBuildVersionCode="23" platformBuildVersionName="6.0-2704002">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" 
 android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" 
  android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application android:banner="@drawable/app_banner" 
android:debuggable="false" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" 
android:isGame="false" android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">

    <activity 
          android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|
         keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigati
        on|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|
        smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" 
        android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" 
         android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" 
        android:value="true"/>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.nianticproject.platform.AccountsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"/>

    <service android:name="com.upsight.android.analytics.internal.DispatcherService"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.extension.analytics" android:value="com.upsight.android.UpsightAnalyticsExtension"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.core" android:value="com.upsight.android.internal.CoreComponentFactory"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.extension.googleadvertisingid" android:value="com.upsight.android.UpsightGoogleAdvertisingIdExtension"/>

    <service android:name="com.upsight.android.googlepushservices.internal.PushIntentService"/>
    <service android:name="com.upsight.android.googlepushservices.internal.PushClickIntentService"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.extension.googlepushservices" android:value="com.upsight.android.UpsightGooglePushServicesExtension"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.extension.managedvariables" android:value="com.upsight.android.UpsightManagedVariablesExtension"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.extension.marketing" android:value="com.upsight.android.UpsightMarketingExtension"/>

    <activity android:name="com.nianticlabs.nia.account.AccountsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.nianticlabs.nia.iap.PurchaseActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>

    <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.nianticlabs.nia.useractivity.ActivityRecognitionService"/>

    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme"/>

    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.nianticproject.holoholo.sfida.service.SfidaService"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.session_callbacks" android:value="com.upsight.android.unity.UnitySessionCallbacks"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.upsight.android.googlepushservices.internal.PushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.nianticlabs.pokemongo"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <provider android:authorities="com.nianticlabs.pokemongo.upsight" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.upsight.android.internal.persistence.ContentProvider"/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.sdk_plugin" android:value="4.0.7"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.app_token" android:value="a9cc12f87adc420baf964f187672ecb4"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.public_key" android:value="MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyYKX0nb1ezY2KLkAl0tuWn2AZ0PfS2NF2BSM0T2OLCJM/H8Siyz1+OTvDWo1w+psbz6ugjTOaBGtkTRI1uikGcu32mhW2I4c9XUUkx1AYlC3wwiqnWZMvMKthp1yaKzrTsqhZzwJ6DvgZHUf1IPIkoxXoGmfyYNRI3QcpW5Uwa1dsZr5YeG8fwC53hyukOutt6PRqwDXQCsyCd/PawjUJZT6oxDFYYZ8a/11OIstlS4jXnQQ+k/f5HV5b8+ITiKhqXuNVsByPZqSIwi5T8pwJan7Rk8OCVImSkgUmWLcmlPcoL1UaF+vMZXZYhk1hM765IUw++7Dw2qvKVi4yl+giwIDAQAB"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.gcm" android:value="com.nianticlabs.pokemongo.GCM_SENDER_ID"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.user_attribute.player_level" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.user_attribute.player_xp" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.user_attribute.player_avatar" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.user_attribute.pokemon_count" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.user_attribute.item_count" android:value="0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.upsight.user_attribute.pokecoin" android:value="0"/>

</application>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>

<permission android:name="com.nianticlabs.pokemongo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.nianticlabs.pokemongo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
```

Here's the Python Code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("AndroidManifest.xml").getroot()

var = root.findall("uses-permission")
#print(var)
n=len(var)
for i in range(n):
 print(var[i].attrib)


var1 = root.findall("uses-feature")
#print(var1)
m=len(var1)
for j in range(m):
 print(var1[j].attrib)


var2 = root.findall("application")
#print(var2)
a=len(var2)
for k in range(a):
 print(var2[k].attrib)


var3 = root.findall("service")
print(var3)

b=len(var3)
for v in range(b):
  print(var3[v].attrib)
```

This code can print the permissions, features used by the Manifest file, but not the services used. What may be the problem? Where I am making the mistake?

Comment: because `service` is not a direct child of the root of your document?

Comment: @pskink Sir, so how can I print all the indirect childs like services and intent filters etc. ? Can you help me with it?

Comment: see `xml.etree.ElementTree` python documentation - it has a lot of examples there

Comment: @pskink Sir, In that documentation ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html ) can you tell me what this line of code is actually wanting to do:    

root = ET.fromstring(country_data_as_string)

Comment: yes, this is that documentation - read it carefully